# Convert a SQL Server table to a shapefile with projection info

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I've been using `ogr2ogr` to write out shapefiles from my SQL Server spatial map layers.  When I run the command it delivers the .shp, .shx, and the .dbf but no prj file.  Is there a way to get `ogr2ogr` to write out the project file from the table?  The projection is just standard SRID = 4326.

Comment: Technically, the `.prj` isn't part of the shapefile standard, but if you know it's `GCS_WGS_1984` you can copy the ASCII file from any existing layer or an `etc` folder in your app directory (named appropriately).

Comment: -s_srs <srs_def>  (example -s_srs EPSG:4326) https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-s_srs or download the .prj and rename the same as your shp/shx/dbf https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/